# Error en conexion a base de datos

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos en `MySQLWorkBench`.

Este es mi archivo `connection.php`

```
<?php

    class MySqlConnection
    {
        //get connection
        public static function getConnection()
        {
            //read config
            $data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sasy/config/connection.json');
            $config = json_decode($data, true);
            //parameters
            if (isset($config['server']))
                $server = $config['server'];
            else {
                echo 'Configuration error : MySql Server name not found';
                die;
            }
            if (isset($config['user']))
                $user = $config['user'];
            else {
                echo 'Configuration error : User name not found';
                die;
            }
            if (isset($config['password']))
                $password = $config['password'];
            else {
                echo 'Configuration error : Password not found';
                die;
            }
            if (isset($config['database']))
                $database = $config['database'];
            else {
                echo 'Configuration error : Database name not found';
                die;
            }
            //open connection
            $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);
            //error in connection
            if ($connection === false) {
                echo 'Could not connect to MySql';
                die;
            }
            //character set
            $connection->set_charset('utf8');
            //return connection object
            return $connection;
        }
    }
?>
```

Y adema tengo este archivo con nombre `connection.js`

```
{
    "server" : "localhost",
    "database" : "sasy",
    "user" : "root",
    "password" : ""
}
```

Tengo la siguiente `Api`:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
//  require_once('connection.php');
  require_once('../models/connection.php');


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
  if(isset($_GET['email_user']) && isset($_GET['password_user']))
  {
     $email_user=$_GET["email_user"];
         $password_user=$_GET["password_user"];
     $connection = new MySqlConnection();

    $query = 'SELECT id_user, email_user,password_user,idCode from users where email_user = ? AND password_user= ?';
    $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($email_user,$password_user));

    if ($result>0)
    {
      $user = json_encode(array(
                'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                                'email_user' => $result[0][1],
                'password_user' => $result[0][2],
                'idCode' => $result[0][3]
              ));
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'user' => json_decode($user)
        ));
    }//if
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 1,
        'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
        ));
    }//else
  }
} //CIERRA IF
?>
```

Al intentar obtener los datos poniendo parametros en postman, me sale lo siguiente:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method
>   MySqlConnection::executeQuery() in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\sasy\apis\login.php** on line **17**

Linea 17:

```
  $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($email_user,$password_user));
```

¿Cual puede ser mi error?

Comment: No estas confundiendo este método`executeQuery` por este otro `execute();` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$connection` no tiene una conexión establecida ya que estás creando una nueva instancia de `MySqlConnection` cuando la conexión la creas desde un método estático.
Deberías hacer:

`$connection = MySqlConnection::getConnection();`

Answer (score 0):

Pato, tienes algunos errores en cuanto a la utilización de los static. Por la forma en que veo que quieres utilizarlo, te recomiendo usar un **singleton**.
Para ello, tu clase debería ser masomenos así:

```
<?php

class MySqlConnection
{
    // instancia de MySqlConnection
    private static $instance = null;

    // previene que se instance la clase
    public function __construct(){}

    //get connection
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        //read config
        $data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sasy/config/connection.json');
        $config = json_decode($data, true);

        // si está instanciado, devuelve la instancia y no abre una nueva conexión
        if(self::$instance !== null) return self::$instance;

        //parameters
        if (isset($config['server']))
            $server = $config['server'];
        else {
            echo 'Configuration error : MySql Server name not found';
            die;
        }
        if (isset($config['user']))
            $user = $config['user'];
        else {
            echo 'Configuration error : User name not found';
            die;
        }
        if (isset($config['password']))
            $password = $config['password'];
        else {
            echo 'Configuration error : Password not found';
            die;
        }
        if (isset($config['database']))
            $database = $config['database'];
        else {
            echo 'Configuration error : Database name not found';
            die;
        }
        //open connection
        //error in connection
        if ($connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database)) {
          //character set
          self::$instance = $connection;
          self::$instance->set_charset('utf8');
          return self::$instance;
        } else {
          echo 'Could not connect to MySql';
          die;
        }
    }
}

// para ejecutar el singleton:
$mysql = MySqlConnection::getConnection();
```

*Nota*: el código no lo he probado, por lo que podría dar algún error. Si no te funciona, deja un comentario y en cuanto pueda lo reviso y lo testeo.